# Arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 4, 3, 5

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a data frame form my list :

```
 > stemmoutput

[[1]]
[1] "tanaman" "cabai"  

[[2]]
[1] "banget"  "hama"    "sakit"   "tanaman"

[[3]]
 [1] "koramil"  "nogosari" "melaks"   "ecek"     "hama"     "tanaman"  "padi"     "ppl"      "ds"       "rambun"  

[[4]]
[1] "tani"    "hama"    "sakit"   "tanaman"

[[5]]
[1] "tani"    "hama"    "sakit"   "tanaman"  NA
```

I am having trouble using `data.frame(stemmoutput)`, I constantly get this error message.

```
Error in data.frame(c("tanaman", "cabai"), c("banget", "hama", "sakit",  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 4, 3, 5
```

Comment: Data frames can only hold rectangular data structures. Each row must have the same number of columns. Your data does not appear to be rectangular so there would be no advantage to storing it in a data.frame. Might as well leave it in a list as is. Otherwise, describe what you think the output should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasonable approaches:

```
data.frame(word = do.call(c, stemoutput),
           group = rep(1:length(stemoutput), 
                       sapply(stemoutput, length)))

require(reshape2)
melt(stemoutput)
```

It's just group labels.