# Interpretting error messages in R, splitting one column into two and creating a new dataframe

Tags: r, error-handling, split, strsplit

I've scraped two tables into R, trimmed them, and now I seek to create new tables by splitting one of the columns of the originals into two. To do this, I've written the following code:

```
page.201702050atl = read_html("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201702050atl.htm")
comments.201702050atl = page.201702050atl %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//comment()")
home.drives.201702050atl = comments.201702050atl[43] %>% html_text() %>% read_html() %>% html_node("#home_drives") %>% html_table()
home.drives.201702050atl.a = home.drives.201702050atl[ , 2:8]
LOS.home.201702050atl = t(data.frame(strsplit(as.character(home.drives.201702050atl.a$LOS), " ", 2)))
LOS.vis.201702050atl = t(data.frame(strsplit(as.character(home.drives.201702050atl.a$LOS), " ", 2)))
```

I've run this code countless times on countless other tables; but, on these two (nearly identical) tables, I seem to be having a problem that I don't understand:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0
```

Can someone please translate this error message into English for me? What is wrong in this particular case? Finally, how do I fix it?

EDIT:

There is a missing cell in row 5 of home.drives.201702050atl. Initially I thought this might be the problem; however, that is why I included the second table. In the second table, there is no missing cell; and yet, I encounter the same error. While it is similar to that of the first table, I did not include the entirety of the coding of the second table in my original post. Please find it below:

```
> page.201702050atl = read_html("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201702050atl.htm")
> comments.201702050atl = page.201702050atl %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//comment()")
> vis.drives.201702050atl = comments.201702050atl[44] %>% html_text() %>% read_html() %>% html_node("#vis_drives") %>% html_table()
> vis.drives.201702050atl.a = vis.drives.201702050atl[ , 2:8]
> LOS.vis.201702050atl = t(data.frame(strsplit(as.character(home.drives.201702050atl.a$LOS), " ", 2)))
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0
```

Comment: Just execute your code step by step and look at the created objects. Then you will see where the chain breaks and will find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147558/arguments-imply-differing-number-of-rows-8-20), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270946/arguments-imply-differing-number-of-rows-2-4-3-5) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814146/r-error-arguments-imply-differing-number-of-rows)?

Comment: I've gone line by line and only encounter an error in line 5, the line which seeks to make a new table. As for the duplication comment, while the posts you cite also encounter the "differing number of rows" error, the build up to it is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the fifth line of your code.

```
home.drives.201702050atl.a %>% 
    `$`(LOS) %>%
    as.character() %>%
    strsplit(., " ", 2) %>%
    purrr::map_int(length)

[1] 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Length of the fifth element is 0. The error is the result of creating a data frame with different number of rows. Getting rid of the fifth element might solve the problem.

Comment: That's what I thought the problem was too, initially. However, there are no missing cells in the second table and I encounter the same error. I should have been more thorough in my explanation of the second table. I will edit my initial post to include the entirety of its coding.